# Rolling or Siding window for transpose of a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transpose

I have the following data:

[image: input data]

I want to obtain it this way:

[image: output data]

What we have manually done here is considered a 3x1 matrix and transposed it to obtain 1x3 matrix for all 4 columns: A1, A2, A3 & A4. I need to automate this process in python, and I believe rolling window is the solution. This needs to iterate through all rows (around 300 odd rows).

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1,1,0,1],
                   'A2': [1,0,0,0],
                   'A3': [1,0,1,1],
                   'A4': [1,0,0,0],
                   })
```

Comment: You must provide an easily reproducible code/text-based input if you want a chance to get a response.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the data samples as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). If you need to read your data from excel, you can e.g. copy the range and use `df = pd.read_clipboard()` first. Show both input *and* expected output, and make sure that they are aligned (i.e. that it is possible to *reach* the expected output fully given the input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) for reshaping:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

N = 3
out = pd.DataFrame(
  sliding_window_view(df, (N,1))
  .reshape(-1,N*df.shape[1]),
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
```

With MultiIndex:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(
  sliding_window_view(df, (N,1))
  .reshape(-1,N*df.shape[1]),
  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, np.arange(N)])
)
```

Output:

```
   A1       A2       A3       A4      
   0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  2
0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1,1,0,1],
                   'A2': [1,0,0,0],
                   'A3': [1,0,1,1],
                   'A4': [1,0,0,0],
                   })
```

Comment: @Addy you're welcome. Quick note, there is a tiny mistake in the dark blue output, the last number should be a 1, maybe correct this for future readers if you can?